# Pinch zoom doesn't work for Phonegap inappbrowser _blank

Tags: phonegap, inappbrowser

I am having the code to open the PDF url in Inappbrowser. I am trying this in Iphone.

cordova.InAppBrowser.open(aPdfURL, '_blank', 'location=no, EnableViewPortScale=yes');

It opens the PDF file, but when I try pinch zoom it is not working.

But if I change it to _system instead of _blank, it opens the SAFARI system browser and shows the PDF url, but then I see the URL in browser, which I don't want to.

Please suggest as to how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<meta>` tag in index.html

For example:

```
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
```

And also make sure to include respective `<Script>` tag in Index.html

For Example:

```
    <!-- Cordova -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- Framework7 library -->
    <script src="framework7/js/framework7.min.js"></script>

    <!-- App routes -->
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>

    <!-- Your custom app scripts -->
    <script src="<custom lib>.js"></script>
```